# Losing data between fluentd and influxdb

Tags: influxdb, fluentd

I'm struggling with data loss between fluentd and influxdb.

Using the fluent-plugin-influxdb plugin with this configuration:

```
<source>
  id test_syslog
  type syslog
  port 42185
  protocol_type tcp
  time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ
  tag test_syslog
  format /^(?<time>[^ ]*) (?<fastly_server>[^ ]*) (?<log_name>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (?<http_method>[^ ]*) (?<http_request>[^ ]*) (?<http_status>[^ ]*) (?<cache_status>[^ ]*) (?<uuid>[^ ]*) *(?<device_model>.*)$/
</source>

<match test_syslog.**>
  type copy
  <store>
    type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/test_syslog
  </store>
  <store>
    id test_syslog
    type influxdb
    dbname test1
    flush_interval 10s
    host localhost
    port 8086
    remove_tag_suffix .local0.info
  </store>
</match>
```

When comparing the file output and the data in influxdb I find this:

```
user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx:/var/log/td-agent# curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "db=test1" --data-urlencode "q=SELECT COUNT(host) FROM log_data" ; cat test_syslog.20150901.b51eb4653c54c63e7 | wc -l
{"results":[{"series":[{"name":"log_data","columns":["time","count"],"values":[["1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",582]]}]}]}2355
```

2355 lines in the log, but only 582 records in the database.

I've enabled debug/trace logging from both influxdb and fluentd but nothing interesting in the logs so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you are writing duplicate points? If the measurement name, tag set, and timestamp match the new point silently overwrites the prior point.

Also, it could be a version mismatch. There was a recent breaking change to the InfluxDB API regarding integers, and it is possible the plugin isn't yet updated to handle that.

Do the InfluxDB logs show failed writes?

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbled over this problem this week.
In my case, the logs are lost because of duplicated points.

I am using fluentd v0.12 which only supports precision to second. The subsecond precision is provided in newer versions see https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/461. Therefore, it is quite easy to have same measurements with same tags and same timestamp

The solution is to use the "sequence_tag" in type influxdb like:

```
  @type influxdb
  host {{INFLUXDB_HOST}}
  port {{INFLUXDB_PORT}}
  dbname {{INFLUXDB_DBNAME}}
  sequence_tag sequence
```

The records with same timestamp will have an additional tag like:

```
time                 requestDurationMillis sequence success testClients testGroup    testRunId
----                 --------------------- -------- ------- ----------- ---------    ---------
2018-01-17T11:09:13Z 530                   0        1       2           warmup       20180117/130908
2018-01-17T11:09:13Z 529                   1        1       2           warmup       20180117/130908
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Regardless of resolution, this will make sure that _nothing_ ever gets lost.

Comment: Wouldn't this be bad for tag cardinality?